# Query to get previous value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenerio where I need previous column value but it should not be same as current column value.

Table A:

```
+------+------+-------------+
| Col1 | Col2 |   Lead_Col2 |
+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | A    | NULL        |
|    2 | B    | A           |
|    3 | B    | A           |
|    4 | C    | B           |
|    5 | C    | B           |
|    6 | C    | B           |
|    7 | D    | C           |
+------+------+-------------+
```

As Given above, I need previuos column(Col2) value. which is not same as current value.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select *
  from (select col1,
               col2,
               lag(col2, 1) over(order by col1) as prev_col2
          from table_a)
 where col2 <> prev_col2
```

Answer (score 0):

The name `lead_col2` is misleading, because you really want a lag.

Here is a brute force method that uses a correlated subquery to get the index of the value and then joins the value in:

```
select aa.col1, aa.col2, aa.col2
from (select col1, col2,
             (select max(col1) as maxcol1
              from a a2
              where a2.id < a.id and a2.col2 <> a.col2
             ) as prev_col1
      from a
     ) aa left join
     a
     on aa.maxcol1 = a.col1
```

EDIT:

You can also use logic with `lead()` and ignore `NULL`s.  If a value is the last in its sequence, then use that value, otherwise set it to `NULL`.  Then use `lag()` with `ignore`NULL`s:

```
select col1, col2,
       lag(col3) over (order by col1 ignore nulls)
from (select col1, col2,
             (case when col2 <> lead(col2) over (order by col1) then col2
              end) as col3
      from a
     ) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.col1
      ,t.col2
      ,first_value(lag_col2) over (partition by col2 order by ord) lag_col2
from (select t.*
            ,case when lag_col2 = col2 then 1 else 0 end  ord
            from (select t.*
                  ,lag (col2) over (order by col1) lag_col2
                  from table1 t
                 )t
     )t
order by col1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95f51/10)